# how i highlighted item in first launch of app in recycle

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have integrated item is highlighted in the first launch of the app in my project.
I'll use to save the selected item on the click of the adapter in the SQL database and set the value in the first launch of the app, but it does not change the background and text color.
please help me in solving the issue and suggest me the right way

```
public class LoadVehicleTypeAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LoadVehicleTypeAdapter.CarTypesHolder> {

private List<TaxiTypeResponse.Message> CarTypesModelsList;
private Context mContext;
VehicleTypeView vehicleTypeView;
int I=-1;
int idd=0;
Activity activity;
GoogleMap map;
int II=-1;
List<VehicleClick> list;
public static String dbname="HellooClick";
public static MyAppRoomDataBase myAppRoomDataBase;


public class CarTypesHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements  View.OnClickListener {
    public CustomTextView mCarType;
    public CircleImageView mCarTypeImage;
    LinearLayout llRoot;
    CardView cardView;
    setOnitemclick listener;
    SparseBooleanArray mSparseArray;
    public void setOnItemClickListner(setOnitemclick listener)
    {
        this.listener=listener;
    }

    public CarTypesHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        mCarType = (CustomTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.frag_cartypes_inflated_name);
        mCarTypeImage = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.frag_cartype_inflated_frameImage);
        llRoot = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.root1);
        cardView=(CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardf);
        mSparseArray=new SparseBooleanArray();


        view.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        mSparseArray.put(getAdapterPosition(), true);
        listener.ImageClick(v,getAdapterPosition());
    }
}


public LoadVehicleTypeAdapter(Context context, List<TaxiTypeResponse.Message> CarTypesModelsList, VehicleTypeView vehicleTypeView,Activity activity,GoogleMap map) {
    this.CarTypesModelsList = CarTypesModelsList;
    mContext = context;
    this.vehicleTypeView = vehicleTypeView;
    this.activity=activity;
    this.map=map;
}



@Override
public CarTypesHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.frag_cartype_inflated_view, parent, false);
    return new CarTypesHolder(itemView);
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final  CarTypesHolder holder, final int position) {
    myAppRoomDataBase=Room.databaseBuilder(activity,MyAppRoomDataBase.class,dbname).allowMainThreadQueries().build();
    list=myAppRoomDataBase.userDao().getAll();
    if(list.size()!=0){
        II= Integer.parseInt(list.get(0).RideId);

    }
    if (II==position)
    {
 holder.llRoot.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));
        holder.mCarType.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    }
    else
    {

    }
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = activity.getSharedPreferences("mSelected", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    TaxiTypeResponse.Message carTypesModel = CarTypesModelsList.get(position);
     holder.mCarType.setText(carTypesModel.getName());
     holder.mCarTypeImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wait);
    int color = Color.parseColor(PreferenceHandler.readString(mContext,PreferenceHandler.SECONDRY_COLOR,"#006fb6"));
    holder.mCarType.setTextColor(color);



    holder.setOnItemClickListner(new setOnitemclick() {
        @Override
        public void ImageClick(View v,int position1) {
            I=position1;
            notifyDataSetChanged();

            if (list.size()!=0)
            {
                myAppRoomDataBase.userDao().delete();
                list.clear();
            }
            VehicleClick vehicleClick=new VehicleClick();
            vehicleClick.setRideId(String.valueOf(position1));
            myAppRoomDataBase.userDao().insert(vehicleClick);
            list.add(vehicleClick);

        }
    });
    if (I==position)
    {

        holder.llRoot.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));
        holder.mCarType.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));


    }
    else
    {

        holder.llRoot.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f3f3f3"));
        holder.mCarType.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2196F3"));

    }

   Picasso.with(mContext).load(carTypesModel.getImagePath()).into(holder.mCarTypeImage);

}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return CarTypesModelsList.get(position).getID();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return CarTypesModelsList.size();
}

public void setSelection(LinearLayout imageView,CustomTextView textView,boolean value,int position){
    if(value){

        imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));
        textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

    }else{
        System.out.println("11111111111111111000000111111111111");
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f3f3f3"));
        textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2196F3"));

     }
 }
 public interface  setOnitemclick{
    void ImageClick(View view,int position);
 }
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}



}
```

Comment: I am not able to understand why are you performing DB operation everytime when onBindView is called
myAppRoomDataBase=Room.databaseBuilder(activity,MyAppRoomDataBase.class,dbname).allowMainThreadQueries().build();
    list=myAppRoomDataBase.userDao().getAll();

Comment: @wasim because I'll set this code is in the main class and I'll load data for highlighted one item always but I'm not able to do this please help us

Comment: @wasim in my updated code I'll set database code to an activity and pass the list into the constructor

Comment: Do you want to highlight the Background using onClickListener. Please share your recycler_item xml which you use for data populate and ViewHolder.

Comment: I have added functionality to change the background of recyclerview in one of my application using onLongPress. please check and let me know if you have the same requirement. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ingris.quick.dialer.speed

Comment: @wasim almost same but I load data with one selected item which I store in a database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185234/discussion-between-wasim-and-mohit-lakhanpal).

Comment: Hope you were able to resolve the problem.